# NgRx Store doesn't get values when components are from different modules - Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am working on an Angular Application which have the following Modules Structure.

`app.module.ts` and within this module, I have two more modules called `home.module.ts` and `admin.module.ts`.

I am using NgRx in my application for state management. What I am trying to do is, when certain event occurs on a component in `home.module.ts`, then the action dispatched here should be reflected in the `app.module.ts` or even in the sibling module `admin.module.ts`. The action dispaching works perfect between two components of a same module (regardless of parent-child or child-parent relation), but not when the the modules are changed.

The `StoreModule` is already included in the `app.module.ts`, I imported it within `home.module.ts` but still no success.

I need help regarding this issue, thank you.

> Also, please note that, the store works perfect among the components of the same module. i.e. Actions get dispatched and even the other component listens to it in the mean time.

**Component 1 to Dispatch Action**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Test } from '../../../ngrx/models/test.model'
import * as TestActions from '../../../ngrx/actions/test.actions'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-test',
  templateUrl: './add-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-test.component.css']
})
export class AddTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public store: Store<Test[]>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addDataToStore(){
    console.log("Action Dispatched... [Add Test]")
    const data = {
      name : "Adnan Khan",
      email : "adnan@khan.com"
    }
    this.store.dispatch(new TestActions.TestAdd(data))
  }

}
```

**Component 2 to Show the Data**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Test } from '../../../ngrx/models/test.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-test',
  templateUrl: './show-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-test.component.css']
})
export class ShowTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public store: Store<Test>
  ) { }

  storeData: Observable<Test[]>

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storeData = this.store.select('test')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An action that is dispatched will be passed to every registered reducer.
If module A dispatches an action, a reducer in Module B will receive the dispatched action.
The only requisite is that Module B is loaded.

More info at [Sharing data between modules is peanuts](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts)

Comment: Yes, the module B is loaded as well but still doesn't work

Comment: If you can reproduce it, I'm happy to take a look.